# Why am I getting a segmentation fault on my pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault

So I'm trying to write a function that returns a newly made Huffman tree, the function finds the two smallest frequencies in a list then removes them (remove_smallest) and then makes them the children of a new treeNode (root) and inserts it into the list again (in the style of Huffman trees) and does it all over until there is 1 element left in the list. My program seems to be crashing around the line just after the second call to the remove_smallest function. The remove_smallest function returns the smallest treeNode in the list It should keep going until there is one element left. Where am I going wrong? Any why am I getting a segmentation fault? As I mentioned it seems to be crashing right after the two calls to remove_smallest.

Am I dereferencing a pointer that's pointing at random memory? or setting an incorrect pointer to something?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Code:

```
typedef TreeNode* Element;
typedef Frequency* TreeElement;

struct TreeNode {

  TreeElement data; //stores a pointer to the data in this tree node
  TreeNode *left; //reference to the left child tree
  TreeNode *right; //reference to the right child tree

};

struct ListNode {
  Element data;  // stores a pointer to data in node
  ListNode *next; // reference to next node in list
};

struct List {
   ListNode *head;  // reference to the first node in the list
   int numElements; // the number of nodes in the list
};

struct HuffmanTree {
  TreeNode *root;
};

struct FrequencyList {
  List *freqs;
};

struct Frequency {
  char data; // the character being represented
  int count; // the number of occurrences of the character
};

    HuffmanTree *createHuffmanTree(FrequencyList *frequencies) {

    List * newList = new List;
    newList = frequencies->freqs;

    TreeNode * newTree1;
    TreeNode * newTree2;
    TreeNode * root = new TreeNode;


        while (frequencies->freqs->numElements != 1) {

            newTree1 = remove_smallest(frequencies); // removes and returns   smallest treeNode from list
            newTree2 = remove_smallest(frequencies);
            root->data->count = newTree1->data->count + newTree2->data->count; 
            root->left = newTree1;
            root->right = newTree2;

            insert(newList, root);  // inserts back into list

        }

        HuffmanTree * newHuffmanTree = new HuffmanTree;
        newHuffmanTree->root = root;

    return newHuffmanTree;

}
```

Comment: 1st Use the debugger to narrow the source of the error. 2nd post a [MCVE] here that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Possibly a problem with `remove_smallest`, or in how the frequency structure is constructed, or in `insert`. Or something else. The only obvious problem with what you posted is the `newList` memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segmentation Fault is caused by trying to access memory that doesn't exist. This is a very common error for people that are new to C/C++. I would double check all your pointers and make sure you are trying to access the information that you intended (address/value).

Comment: This should have been a comment.

Comment: I figured it out, I was trying to access a struct that I hadn't established yet and thus accessing memory that hadn't existed yet. Thank you @Koverman47